# Unity 3D: how to make boundaries using cinemachine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I am trying to achieve same camera settings as in the video I am attaching below

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jtb3D9qzOE3NYC6DuWkDCXflPWYT-nuz/view?usp=drivesdk

My project have similar concept as in the video, you go up on tapping and thus I want to achieve the same camera settings

As you can see, when I tap and cube goes up the camera starts moving only after cube have reaches a certain position, and after going up a bit the camera locks and doesn't allow to go down anymore. I want to have same as this, go up and camera moves after a certain position and after a certain distance it locks. I am using cinemachine. I am kinda new to it, so any coding help is appreciated. Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Cinemachine Confiner, which limits the camera movement to a given volume.

See here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.3/manual/CinemachineConfiner.html

~Pino

Comment: Thanks alot, I really don't get the down votes, what did I do wrong. But thanks a lot I checked it, but I have a question can it move along with the character?

Comment: No idea why the down votes, really. The virtual camera can totally follow the player and also focus on it. You can learn all the tricks of Cinemachine here: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/cinemachine